# D3js How to format the content of some columns in a table

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've this code of an interactive table made with d3 and it's running just fine. The only problem is that I want the second and third columns contents to be shown as percentage.
The csv file I'm working with look like this:

```
CSV
date,kind1,kind2,place
17/03/2014,0.28,0.46,NY
....
```

I suppose I need to use the map function again but I'm getting confused, any help?

```
 var table = d3.select("body")
    .append("table")
    .attr("class", "table"),
    thead = table.append("thead"),
    tbody = table.append("tbody");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data){

var columns = Object.keys(data[0])

var header = thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
        .text(function(d){ return d;});

var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("tr")
    .on("mouseover", function(d){
        d3.select(this)
            .style("background-color", "orange");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d){
        d3.select(this)
            .style("background-color","transparent");
    });

var cells = rows.selectAll("td ")
    .data(function(row){
        return columns.map(function(d, i){
            return {i: d, value: row[d]};
        });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .html(function(d){ return d.value;});`
```

`

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your goal would be to change the callback on the last line from this:

```
.html(function(d){ return d.value;})
```

to this:

```
.html(function(d,i){ if(i == 1 || i == 2) return (d.value*100) + '%'; return d.value; })
```

This takes advantage of the way d3 calls all functors with both the data and the index. Depending on your data there might be better ways than looking at the index.

---

Alternatively, you could add the percentage signs up front after reading the data:

```
data.forEach(function(d) { d[1] = (d[1]*100)+'%'; d[2] = (d[2]*100)+'%'; })
```

This approach limits your ability to do other calculations with the data at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend changing the last line to:

```
.html(function(d){ return typeof(d.value)==="number"?(100*d.value).toFixed(1)+"%":d.value;});
```

This changes all the attributes which are of number type (in your case kind1 and kind2) to a percentage, with decimal precision given in the parameter of the `.toFixed()` call.

Comment: It's very unlikely that OP will have a NaN in his dataset, but have in mind that `typeof NaN === 'number'` returns true.

Comment: You are the one knowing your data. If that can be a problem, how about `typeof(d.value)==="string"` and swapping the commands in the ternary operator?

Comment: I don't know any data, I'm not the OP. I was just telling you that `typeof` will return "number" for NaN.

Comment: Sorry, @GerardoFurtado, I addressed that to the OP, although replying to your comment. Your point is totally valid, but even if the dataset contains some NaN elements, I think my suggestion can be corrected, and then it provides a solution, which is not column-index based, but relies on the content of the dataset.

Comment: Instead of complicating the code with `toFixed`, etc. you could use [d3.format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format): `d3.format('.1%')(d.value)`

Comment: Indeed I've this NaN result in the first and third column. I think the first column can be fixed with a parsedate function, but I find myself in trouble with the ternary operator.

Comment: @Michele, then you indeed need a solution based on column indices. Like the one Owen suggested in his answer.